# Is there a set $A \subset \mathbb{N}$ s.t. $A$ is not the interpretation set of any formula in Peano arithmetic?

Tags: first-order-logic, peano-axioms

More formally, what I want to find is a set $A \subset \mathbb{N}$ s.t. for every formula $\phi$ with only one free variable $x$ in Peano arithmetic, there exists $a \in A$ s.t. $\{ x \mapsto a \} \not\models \phi$.

Intuitively, I think the set of Fibonacci numbers cannot be the interpretation set of any formula in Peano arithmetic, but I don't know how to prove that.

Comment: There are only countably many formulas...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Ohhh...got it, do you mean that $A$ could be constructed in a way like Cantor's diagonal argument?

Comment: Meanwhile, via the usual "sequence trick" involving the $\beta$-function, the set of Fibonacci numbers (and, indeed, practically any set you can concretely describe) **is** in fact definable in the language of arithmetic. All computable sets are even *representable in PA*, which is a stronger condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for @David C. Ullrich.

There are only countably many formulas, but the power set of natural numbers is uncountable. Thus, all sets that could be represented by some formula are countable, which is a proper subset of $2^\mathbb{N}$. Thus, there must be some $A \subset \mathbb{N}$ s.t. $A$ cannot be represented by any formula.

Answer (score 1):

We can do better than a cardinality argument. By [Tarski's undefinability theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski%27s_undefinability_theorem) we can take $A$ to be the set of Godel codes of the true statements of Peano arithmetic.